# How do I convince Angular to look at the route on the path when reloading page?

Tags: angularjs

So, I have some code like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .controller("main", MainController)
    .controller("about", AboutController)
    .controller("contact", ContactController)
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "views/about.html",
            controller: "about"
        });
        $routeProvider.when("/contact", {
            templateUrl: "views/contact.html",
            controller: "contact"
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: "main"
        });
    });

function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.showMain = showMain;
    $scope.showAbout = showAbout;
    $scope.showContact = showContact;

    $scope.showMain();

    function setView(view) {
        $scope.view = view;
    }

    function showMain() {
        setView('main');
    }

    function showAbout() {
        setView('about');
    }

    function showContact() {
        setView('contact');
    }
}

function AboutController($scope) {}

function ContactController($scope) {}
```

and it works fine. I have some HTML like this:

```
        <header role="banner" class="top_bar row">
            <div class="col span_3">
                <nav>
                <a href="/" ng-click="showMain()">home</a>
                    <a href="#/about" ng-click="showAbout()">about</a>
                    <a href="#/contact" ng-click="showContact()">contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main role="main">
        <div ng-show="view=='main'">
            <div ng-include="'views/main.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="view=='about'">
            <div ng-include="'views/about.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="view=='contact'">
            <div ng-include="'views/contact.html'"></div>
        </div>
        </main>
```

and together, it works like I want it to. As I click the links, the proper content is displayed, but if I'm on a url like mysite.com/#/about and I reload the page (CTRL-F5 in the browser), it reloads the main.html content, even though the address bar still says mysite.com/#/about.

How can I fix this so that either:

1. The path in the address bar is evaluated on a reload and the proper content is displayed

or

2. The address bar is changed to the root, matching the content shown?

Help is always appreciated.

V

Comment: Any reason you're not using `ng-view` and allowing angular to load the templates for you? The way you're doing it doesn't actually make proper use of angular routes. From your code, it looks like you set the view from you `MainController` only so when your page reloads, no view is actually set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove what is inside `<main>` and, use the directive ng-view ( [angular docs about ng-view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) )
- Remove ng-click directive from links.
- Remove what is inside your mainController, exclude just the date line ($scope.date)